# How can I prevent the WordPress Importer from munging double-newline paragraph breaks to a single newline?

Tags: import, bulk-import

When you import posts with the standard [WP Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/) plugin, most users are going to find that it changes the standard paragraph break sequence of `\n\n` to a single `\n`. When it comes time to display the post later, this will prevent [`wpautop()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/) from wrapping consecutive paragraphs in `<p>...</p>` tags, instead replacing the break between them with a `<br />`.

Answer (score 1):

I banged my head on the wall for hours before I realized there was a simple solution I could use to pre-process the import XML file prior to running WP Importer. The solution is to just run the file through a home-grown filter program that runs `wpautop()` on the content before it has a chance to get munged by the plugin.

Since getting the content blocks out of the input XML is a little tedious, I decided to share my code with the community to kick-start your next import. The code and a lengthier explanation are at "[WordPress import with wpautop](https://scotthom.com/2018/12/wordpress-import-with-wpautop/)". I'll include the PHP code here for preservation within StackExchange:

```
$accum  = 0;
$buffer = '';

while ( $line = fgets( STDIN ) ) {
    $line = preg_replace( '/\r\n/', "\n", $line );
    $line = preg_replace( '/\r/',   "\n", $line );

    $start = false;
    $end   = false;
    if ( preg_match( '/^\s*<content:encoded><!\[CDATA\[/', $line ) ) {
        $line = preg_replace( '/^\s*<content:encoded><!\[CDATA\[/', '', $line ); 
        $start = true; 
    } 
    if ( preg_match( '/\]\]><\/content:encoded>\s*$/i', $line ) ) {
        $line = preg_replace( '/\]\]><\/content:encoded>\s*$/i', '', $line );
        $end = true;
    }

    if ( $start && $end ) {
        echo $line;
    } elseif ( $start ) {
        $accum = true;
        $buffer = $line;
    } elseif ( $end ) {
        $accum = false;
        $buffer .= $line;
        echo '<content:encoded><![CDATA[' . wpautop( $buffer ) . ']]></content:encoded>';
    } else {
        if ( $accum ) {
            $buffer .= $line;
        } else {
            echo $line;
        }
    }
}

exit(0);
```

This technique relies on being able to run wpautop() from inside a plain ol' command line program. See "[Using WordPress in a non-interactive 'batch' CLI process](https://scotthom.com/2018/10/using-wordpress-in-a-non-interactive-batch-cli-process/)" for details on how to do that.